# How to get the share count of an update in LinkedIn

Tags: share, linkedin-api

In the following two links is explained how to get the updates for a `user` and a `company` respectively. They both return the `likes` and `comments` count for each update, but the `share/reshare` count is completely missing.

Does anybody know how to get the `share/reshare` statistics for an update?

- user: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api
- company: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields

Comment: Looking for the same, Able to get likes and comments but the shares count. Please post here if you have resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337/historical-status-update-statistics:(share-count)?time-granularity=month&start-timestamp=1474647365000&update-key=<updateKey>&format=json
```

Documentation is extremely poor on this api. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#historical_updates
But likes, comments, impressions, shares and click counts are all supported as metrics with this api and seemingly real time but in my experience it is not updated real time.